# Valgrind errors even though all heap blocks were freed

Tags: c, valgrind

I have recently developed a habit of running all of my programs through `valgrind` to check for memory leaks, but most of its results have been a bit cryptic for me.

For my latest run, `valgrind -v` gave me:

```
All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

That means my program's covered for **memory leaks**, right?

So what does this error mean? Is my program not reading certain memory blocks correctly?

```
ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 14 from 9)

1 errors in context 1 of 1:
Invalid read of size 4
   at 0x804885B: findPos (in /home/a.out)
   by 0xADD918: start_thread (pthread_create.c:301)
   by 0xA26CCD: clone (clone.S:133)
 Address 0x4a27108 is 0 bytes after a block of size 40 alloc'd
   at 0x4005BDC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
   by 0x804892F: readInput (in /home/a.out)
   by 0xADD918: start_thread (pthread_create.c:301)
   by 0xA26CCD: clone (clone.S:133)

used_suppression:     14 dl-hack3-cond-1
```

Also, what are the so-called "suppressed" errors here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Yes, you are greatly covered, don't
   think that valgrind easily can miss
   a leak in user code
2. your error means that you probably
   have a +1 error in indexing an array
   variable. the lines that valgrind
   tell you should be accurate, so you
   should easily find that, provided you compile all your code with `-g`
3. suppressed errors are usually from
   system libraries, which sometimes have small leaks or undectable things like the state variables of threads. your manual page should list the suppression file that is used by default

Comment: This is one of the suppressed errors, it just gave me "1 error suppressed" when I used valgrind without -v. So, it's not my headache, right?

Comment: @crypto: you mean the error in `findPos`? No this one is for real, this is your code that is doing something wrong. Without the code itself I can only guess, but from the naming of the function I'd guess that this scans an array and runs beyond the allocated bound in some border case. Compile with `-g` and valgrind will tell you the exact line.

Comment: But the final location of error is stated as clone.S, over which I have no control.

Comment: @crypto: no this is not the final error location. This is just the bottom of the call stack which is given by valgrind for information, so you see where the erroneous call comes from. The error is on top of the stack in `findPos`.

Comment: also run with `--leak-check=full` (i'm not in linux atm, i think this is right)

Answer (score 22):

This seems obvious ... but it might be worth pointing out that the `"no leaks are possible"` message does not mean that your program cannot leak; it just means that it did not leak in the configuration under which it was tested.

If I run the following with valgrind with no command line parameters, it informs me that no leaks are possible.  But it does leak if I provide a command line parameter.

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   if ( argc > 1 )
      malloc( 5 );
   printf( "Enter any command line arg to cause a leak\n" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking for memory leaks is one reason to use valgrind, but I'd say a better reason is to find more serious errors in your code, such as using an invalid array subscript or dereferencing an uninitialized pointer or a pointer to freed memory.

It's good if valgrind tells you that the code paths you exercised while running valgrind didn't result in memory leaks, but don't let that cause you to ignore reports of more serious errors, such as the one you're seeing here.

As other have suggested, rerunning valgrind after compiling with debug information (-g) would be a good next step.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting below error:- 
"Invalid read of size 4"

Are you freeing memory before and then go to next argument?
I am also getting error because in linked list I am freeing memory first and then go to next element.
Below is my code snippet where I am getting error -

```
void free_memory(Llist **head_ref)
{
    Llist *current=NULL;

    current=*head_ref;
    while(*head_ref != NULL)
    {
        current=*head_ref;
        free(current);
        current=NULL;
        (*head_ref)=(*head_ref)->next;
    }
}
```

After changes below is my code snippet -

```
void free_memory(Llist **head_ref)
{
    Llist *current=NULL;
    current=*head_ref;
    while(*head_ref != NULL)
    {
        current=*head_ref;
        (*head_ref)=(*head_ref)->next;
        free(current);
        current=NULL;
     }
 }
```